# canceled while creating documents in cosmosdb

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

We are using cosmosdb to log our application logs. Our logs have two one layer have  general info and other have more detailed information of the general log. We also log a copy of these in other two collections for backup. So we have completely four collections. In our code we are using Async CreateDocumentAsync to create these logs. We are storing the Task in a list and using Task.WaitAll to complete all the tasks. In dev environment we did not see any errors but in production we are seeing  canceled errors in our application insights when creating new documents. sample picture below.

[image: Error info from application insights of API]

Below is the code structure we are using

API Controller code

```
public void Log(LogModel logObject)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Save(logObject);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _azureTelemtry.TrackTrace($"Exception occured: {ex.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

Context save method

```
public void Save(LogModel logObject)
{
    List<Task> saveTasks = new List<Task>();
    LogInfo logInfo = logObject.logInfo;
    LogDetails logDetails = logObject.logDetails;
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, primaryLogInfoCollectionID), logInfo));
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, archieveLogInfoCollectionID), logInfo));    
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, primaryLogDetailsCollectionID), logDetails));
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, archieveLogDetailsCollectionID), logDetails));
    Task.WaitAll(saveTasks.ToArrays());
}
```

Exception Details

> System.AggregateException:    at
>   MyApplication.Logging.Controllers.ApiController.Log
>   (MyApplication.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMyApplication.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   C:\TFS\CA\Logging\Release\Release
>   3.0-Hotfix\Logging\Controllers\ApiController.csMyApplication.Logging, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 57)    at
>   lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor+<>c__DisplayClass33_0.b__0
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__12.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__10.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+d__14.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__22.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__17.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+d__15.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+d__4.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+d__11.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, Version=2.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware+d__3.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1+d__2.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=2.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60) Inner exception
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException handled at
>   MyApplication.Logging.Controllers.ApiController.Log:

Answer (score 1):

You do not await tasks. Besides `Save` function is synchronous thus `Task.WaitAll(saveTasks.ToArrays()); runs synchronpusly`.

At least I expect that `public void Save(LogModel logObject)` would be `public Task Save(LogModel logObject)` and `Task.WaitAll(saveTasks.ToArrays());` would be `return Task.WhenAll(saveTasks.ToArrays());`

```
public Task Save(LogModel logObject)
{
    List<Task> saveTasks = new List<Task>();
    LogInfo logInfo = logObject.logInfo;
    LogDetails logDetails = logObject.logDetails;
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, primaryLogInfoCollectionID), logInfo));
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, archieveLogInfoCollectionID), logInfo));    
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, primaryLogDetailsCollectionID), logDetails));
    saveTasks.Add(documentClient.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, archieveLogDetailsCollectionID), logDetails));

    return Task.WhenAll(saveTasks.ToArrays());
}
```

if your intention is to fire task and forget, now you can use `_context.Save(logObject);` but otherwise you need to use `Task`

another problem is: above code opens 4 tasks and process it uncontrollably. The default Concurrent Execution Limit in .Net Core is 10. Now think that `Save` method called three times one after another and none is finished yet. This means that you need to have 12 concurrent tasks. But .Net Core has limit to 10. Which I believe the last two tasks will be cancelled.

Comment: Also read the Do and Don't from https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md

Comment: The limit of 10 comes in conjunction about how many requests an ASP core server handles concurrent (and even this is [not true anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57464376/1838048)). But this has nothing to do with concurrent tasks. The number of concurrent tasks is depending of the number of available threads. But even this doesn't mean that tasks are cancelled, they are just queued and will be done *later*. The error here is that the tasks are not awaited, get out of scope and will be garbage collected.