# What is the maximum number of requests that ASP.NET Core WebAPI can handle simultaneously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Wondering is there a limit that can be clearly defined in a ASP.NET Core Web API to handle simultaneously several requests / controllers actions.

AFAIK, every action is handled on a thread from the thread-pool, wondering if that can be increased or decreased with ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Kestrel as the underlying web server the default number of concurrent connections in ASP.NET Core 2.2 is defined as unlimited.

- [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxconcurrentconnections?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServerLimits_MaxConcurrentConnections)
- [Kestrel Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#maximum-client-connections)

Comment: I was reading https://www.tpeczek.com/2017/08/implementing-concurrent-requests-limit.html
But yea I guess the official document will do too. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is 1 port 80 and 1 port 443. So at a time only 1 connection can be made?